# curl, ftp upload huge file: Operation timed out after 240000 milliseconds with 24514592768 bytes received

Tags: file-upload, curl, ftp, libcurl, ftp-client

iam trying to upload 250 gb file with ftp... iam using ssh channel for checksum controls...

got this error:

```
curl -v -m 240 --disable-epsv --ftp-skip-pasv-ip --quote "TYPE I" -T 28.tar         ftp://ftpkxxx:xxx@213.65.123.123/2012/12/

[root@tester /opt/tester/output]# ./send-logs-to-194.sh
* About to connect() to 213.65.123.123 port 21 (#0)
*   Trying 213.65.123.123...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time      Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0connected
* Connected to 213.65.123.123 (213.65.123.123) port 21 (#0)
< 220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
> USER ftpkxxx
< 331 Please specify the password.
> PASS xxx
< 230 Login successful.
> PWD
< 257 "/str1/tester_data_backup"
* Entry path is '/str1/tester_data_backup'
> TYPE I
< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
> CWD 2012
< 250 Directory successfully changed.
> CWD 12
< 250 Directory successfully changed.
> PASV
* Connect data stream passively
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (217,65,190,194,29,15).
* Skips 213.65.123.123 for data connection, uses 213.65.123.123 instead
*   Trying 213.65.123.123... connected
* Connecting to 213.65.123.123 (213.65.123.123) port 7439
> TYPE I
< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
> STOR 28.tar
< 150 Ok to send data.
} [data not shown]
  9  250G    0     0    9 22.7G      0  97.3M  0:43:55  0:03:59  0:39:56  102M*         Operation timed out after 240000 milliseconds with 24514592768 bytes received
  9  250G    0     0    9 22.8G      0  97.4M  0:43:54  0:03:59  0:39:55  102M* Closing     connection #0

curl: (28) Operation timed out after 240000 milliseconds with 24514592768 bytes received
```

i prefer ftp instead of scp, beceause it s faster than scp... what is the correct way to upload 250gb file with ftp & checksum?

Answer (score 0):

You specify the maximum time it is allowed to take with -m (240 seconds), so why is it an error for you then when it in fact stops after 240 seconds as you asked it to?

PS. TYPE I is used by default...

Comment: you are right, "-m 240 " removed... trying again... is this the correct and fastest way for big file transfers?...

what do you advise for checksums?

Comment: FTP has no standard way to handle checksums. Possibly using a separate SSH command for that is the best.